# @DataProvider + @Factory + Hashmaps

Tags: automation, testng, factory, dataprovider

Facing compilation error when using `@Factory` with `@DataProvider`.
Trying to map `hashmap` to my `dataprovider`, and want to run all my testcase with first `testdata` row then next, so trying to use `@Factory`

```java
HashMap < String, String testdata = new HashMap < String, String();


@Test
private void test_01() {
 System.out.println(testdata.get("-some-hashmap-key-"));
}

@DataProvider
public static Object[][] getDataSet() {
 int i = 0;
 Object[][] dataSet = new Object[2][1];
 HashMap < String, String > rowValuesMap = new HashMap();
 for (-some logic - ) {
  for (-some logic - ) {
   dataSet[i][0] = rowValuesMap;
  }
  i++;
 }
 return dataSet;
}

@Factory(dataProvider = "getDataSet")
public MyTestFile(HashMap < String, String testdata) {
 this.testdata = sheetdata;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HashMap declaration is wrong in all place. Try this

```java
HashMap < String, String > testdata = new HashMap < String, String > ();

@Test
private void test_01() {
 System.out.println(testdata.get("-some-hashmap-key-"));
}

@DataProvider
public static Object[][] getDataSet() {
 int i = 0;
 Object[][] dataSet = new Object[2][1];
 HashMap < String, String > rowValuesMap = new HashMap < String, String > ();
 for (-some logic - ) {
  for (-some logic - ) {
   dataSet[i][0] = rowValuesMap;
  }
  i++;
 }
 return dataSet;
}

@Factory(dataProvider = "getDataSet")
public MyTestFile(HashMap < String, String > testdata) {
 this.testdata = sheetdata;
}
```